# Plotting Statistical Plots like Volcano in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, plot, statistics

I want to plot graphs like Volcano Plot, MA Plot and BCV Plot for datasets using JavaScript and/or Node.js
Is there anything available that I can use to be able to plot it?

PS: I used d3 but its too cumbersome when it comes to these Plots.

Answer (score 0):

http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries/
Here's an article listing 50 different javascript libraries that support plotting. Hope you find what you're looking for.